# Convert Oracle stored procedure to SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, oracle, stored-procedures

Dear all can any one help me to convert the following Oracle stored procedure 
to SQL Server Version

```
CREATE  PROCEDURE Schedule_Employees (
param_from          IN VARCHAR2,
param_to            IN VARCHAR2,
param_template_id   IN NUMBER)
AS
start_date      NUMBER;
end_date        NUMBER;
template_type   NUMBER;
rec_no          NUMBER;
days_no         NUMERIC;
day_date        VARCHAR2 (20);
shifts_value    VARCHAR2 (10);
current_shift   VARCHAR2 (10) := '-1';
current_index   NUMERIC := 0;
rec_column       VARCHAR (1);
BEGIN
start_date := TO_NUMBER (TO_CHAR (TO_DATE (param_from, 'dd/MM/yyyy'), 'j'));
end_date := TO_NUMBER (TO_CHAR (TO_DATE (param_to, 'dd/MM/yyyy'), 'j'));

FOR cur_r IN start_date .. end_date
LOOP
  day_date := TO_CHAR (TO_DATE (cur_r, 'j'), 'dd/MM/RRRR');

  FOR employees IN (SELECT EmpID FROM EmployeesTempList)
  LOOP
     SELECT TYPE
       INTO template_type
        FROM WORKSCHEDULES
       WHERE SCHEDULEID = param_template_id;

      SELECT RECNO
       INTO rec_no
       FROM WORKSCHEDULES
      WHERE SCHEDULEID = param_template_id;

     SELECT DAYSNO
       INTO days_no
       FROM WORKSCHEDULES
      WHERE SCHEDULEID = param_template_id;

     IF template_type = 2
     THEN
        SELECT RECURRCEVALUES
          INTO shifts_value
          FROM WORKSCHEDULESDYNAMICDETAILS
         WHERE WORKSCHEDULESID = param_template_id
               AND DAYID = MOD (current_index, days_no);

        SELECT ShiftID
          INTO current_shift
          FROM (WITH DATA AS (SELECT shifts_value str FROM DUAL)
                    SELECT ROWNUM AS ID,
                           TRIM (REGEXP_SUBSTR (str,
                                                '[^-]+',
                                                1,
                                                LEVEL))
                              ShiftID
                      FROM DATA
                CONNECT BY INSTR (str,
                                  '-',
                                  1,
                                  LEVEL - 1) > 0)
         WHERE ID = GetRecurrence (current_index, days_no, rec_no);
     ELSE
        rec_column := GetRecurrence (current_index, 7, 4);
        CASE
            WHEN rec_column = 1 THEN select RECUR1 into current_shift from WORKSCHEDULESDETAILS where WORKSCHEDULESID = param_template_id  and DAYID= ((select to_char(to_date(day_date,'dd/MM/yyyy'),'D') from dual) - 1);
            WHEN rec_column = 2 THEN select RECUR2 into current_shift from WORKSCHEDULESDETAILS where WORKSCHEDULESID = param_template_id  and DAYID= ((select to_char(to_date(day_date,'dd/MM/yyyy'),'D') from dual) - 1);
            WHEN rec_column = 3 THEN select RECUR3 into current_shift from WORKSCHEDULESDETAILS where WORKSCHEDULESID = param_template_id  and DAYID= ((select to_char(to_date(day_date,'dd/MM/yyyy'),'D') from dual) - 1);
            WHEN rec_column = 4 THEN select RECUR4 into current_shift from WORKSCHEDULESDETAILS where WORKSCHEDULESID = param_template_id  and DAYID= ((select to_char(to_date(day_date,'dd/MM/yyyy'),'D') from dual) - 1);
        END CASE;
     END IF;

     DELETE FROM ScheduleEmployees
           WHERE EMPLOYEEID = employees.EmpID
                 AND DAYDATE = TO_DATE (day_date, 'dd/MM/yyyy');

     INSERT INTO ScheduleEmployees (SCHEDULEID,
                                    EMPLOYEEID,
                                    FROMDATE,
                                    TODATE,
                                    DAYDATE,
                                    SHIFTS,
                                    CREATEDATE)
          VALUES (param_template_id,
                   employees.EmpID,
                  TO_DATE (param_from, 'dd/MM/yyyy'),
                  TO_DATE (param_to, 'dd/MM/yyyy'),
                  TO_DATE (day_date, 'dd/MM/yyyy'),
                  current_shift,
                  SYSDATE);
   END LOOP;

   current_index := current_index + 1;
END LOOP;
 DELETE FROM EmployeesTempList;
  COMMIT;
END;
/
```

What I have tried

```
       CREATE  PROCEDURE Schedule_Employees (
       @param_from          VARCHAR(4000),
       @param_to            VARCHAR(4000),
       @param_template_id   FLOAT)
       AS
       BEGIN
       DECLARE @start_date      FLOAT;
       DECLARE @end_date        FLOAT;
       DECLARE @template_type   FLOAT;
       DECLARE @rec_no          FLOAT;
       DECLARE @days_no         NUMERIC(38,0);
       DECLARE @day_date        VARCHAR (20);
       DECLARE @shifts_value    VARCHAR (10);
       DECLARE @current_shift   VARCHAR (10) = '-1';
       DECLARE @current_index   NUMERIC(38,0) = 0;
       DECLARE @rec_column       VARCHAR (1);
       SET NOCOUNT ON;
       SET @start_date = TO_NUMBER (TO_CHAR (CONVERT (DATETIME, @param_from, 
       'dd/MM/yyyy'), 'j'));
       SET @end_date = TO_NUMBER (TO_CHAR (CONVERT (DATETIME, @param_to, 
        'dd/MM/yyyy'), 'j'));
```

```
   DECLARE cur_r CURSOR FOR start_date .. end_date
   OPEN cur_r;
   FETCH cur_r INTO;
   WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
   BEGIN
     SET @day_date = TO_CHAR (CONVERT (DATETIME, cur_r, 'j'), 'dd/MM/RRRR');

    DECLARE employees CURSOR FOR SELECT EmpID FROM EmployeesTempList;
    OPEN employees;
    FETCH employees INTO;
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS=0
    BEGIN
       SELECT @template_type = TYPE
       FROM WORKSCHEDULES
       WHERE SCHEDULEID = @param_template_id;

       SELECT @rec_no = RECNO
       FROM WORKSCHEDULES
       WHERE SCHEDULEID = @param_template_id;

       SELECT @days_no = DAYSNO
       FROM WORKSCHEDULES
       WHERE SCHEDULEID = @param_template_id;

       IF @template_type = 2
       BEGIN
        SELECT @shifts_value = RECURRCEVALUES
          FROM WORKSCHEDULESDYNAMICDETAILS
          WHERE WORKSCHEDULESID = @param_template_id
               AND DAYID = (@current_index % @days_no);

         SELECT @current_shift = ShiftID
          FROM (WITH DATA AS (SELECT @shifts_value str)
                    SELECT ROWNUM AS ID,
                           RTRIM(LTRIM (REGEXP_SUBSTR (str,
                                                '[^-]+',
                                                1,
                                                LEVEL))
                              ShiftID
                      FROM DATA
                CONNECT BY INSTR (str,
                                  '-',
                                  1,
                                  LEVEL - 1) > 0)
         WHERE ID = GetRecurrence (@current_index, @days_no, @rec_no);
     END
     ELSE BEGIN
        SET @rec_column = GetRecurrence (@current_index, 7, 4);
        CASE
            WHEN @rec_column = 1 THEN select @current_shift = RECUR1 from WORKSCHEDULESDETAILS where WORKSCHEDULESID = @param_template_id  and DAYID= ((select to_char(convert(DATETIME, @day_date,'dd/MM/yyyy'),'D')) - 1);
            WHEN @rec_column = 2 THEN select @current_shift = RECUR2 from WORKSCHEDULESDETAILS where WORKSCHEDULESID = @param_template_id  and DAYID= ((select to_char(convert(DATETIME, @day_date,'dd/MM/yyyy'),'D')) - 1);
            WHEN @rec_column = 3 THEN select @current_shift = RECUR3 from WORKSCHEDULESDETAILS where WORKSCHEDULESID = @param_template_id  and DAYID= ((select to_char(convert(DATETIME, @day_date,'dd/MM/yyyy'),'D')) - 1);
            WHEN @rec_column = 4 THEN select @current_shift = RECUR4 from WORKSCHEDULESDETAILS where WORKSCHEDULESID = @param_template_id  and DAYID= ((select to_char(convert(DATETIME, @day_date,'dd/MM/yyyy'),'D')) - 1);
        END CASE;
     END 

     DELETE FROM ScheduleEmployees
           WHERE EMPLOYEEID = employees.EmpID
                 AND DAYDATE = CONVERT (DATETIME, @day_date, 'dd/MM/yyyy');

     INSERT INTO ScheduleEmployees (SCHEDULEID,
                                    EMPLOYEEID,
                                    FROMDATE,
                                    TODATE,
                                    DAYDATE,
                                    SHIFTS,
                                    CREATEDATE)
          VALUES (@param_template_id,
                   employees.EmpID,
                  CONVERT (DATETIME, @param_from, 'dd/MM/yyyy'),
                  CONVERT (DATETIME, @param_to, 'dd/MM/yyyy'),
                  CONVERT (DATETIME, @day_date, 'dd/MM/yyyy'),
                  @current_shift,
                  GETDATE());
  FETCH employees INTO;
  END;
  CLOSE employees;
  DEALLOCATE employees;

  SET @current_index = @current_index + 1;
  FETCH cur_r INTO;
  END;
  CLOSE cur_r;
  DEALLOCATE cur_r;
  DELETE FROM EmployeesTempList;
  COMMIT;
  END;
  GO
```

Comment: Can you provide data to test?

Comment: Your datatypes are problematic but it seems to start in oracle. Why are you using numbers instead of dates? That is the point of datatypes, to use the correct one for the data. And cursors in oracle are not as bad as sql server but there is no need for loops and cursors here. This can be set based, and it should have been set based in oracle also.